# SQL- Selecting Columns based on Date and Batch Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

I'm close, now I am just having trouble with this code. It says I need to add exists somewhere? Thanks for the help!

```
SELECT (SELECT UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.NS_Inlet_T
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.NSFlowRate
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.NSHeaterTank
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.NS_Outlet_T
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.NSTrPrAvg
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.NSPump1
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.NSPump2
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.NS_Visc
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.NS_Burner_B
             WHERE
               UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.NSHeatBatch = 'G23169') AS expr1
          , (SELECT UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.OS_Inlet_T
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.OS_Outlet_T
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.OS_Burner_B
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.OSViscosity
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.OSHeaterTank
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.OSPump1
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.OSPump2
                  , UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.OSTrPrAvg
             WHERE
               UA#SacmiDataLog_2013.OSHeatBatch = 'G23169') AS expr2
```

FROM
  dbo.UA#SacmiDataLog_2013

Comment: So lets say G22166 was made on 1/1/13 on the new side. On the old side G22166 was made again on 4/1/13. Is there a way I pick the date 4/1/13 and have only the Old Side data come up?

Comment: I'm confused because you say that a batch could be produced on both sides, and yet you say you need to only select results from the side where the batch is being produced.  It would help to see a better view of the table structure.

Comment: Looking at your most recent comment there, my answer, given the information you've shared, is sure: only select from the OSHeatBatch column.  Your WHERE clause is looking at the NS and OS columns.  But again, I'm betting I don't have enough info to correctly answer this.

EDIT: Or are you saying you only want to see the most recently entered batch?

Comment: It wont let me add an image so let me try and edit it to make it easier to understand

Comment: You certainly can add images here, but tell you what, it would really help if you added your query as it is now, as well as the results you're receiving.  You can just add this as text (there is a button for formatting as code in the editor).  Then you could more easily explain what results you would like to see.

Comment: I need a reputation level of 10 to add images but OK.

Comment: I just voted up your question so you have reputation to do so.  Also, you posted your query, but you say you're getting OS values in your query and it doesn't mention them.  BTW, whoever designed this table/view is making your job difficult as you are finding out.

Comment: Thanks for the help but again, when I post an image it denies it saying I need a reputation of 10. But when I use a where clause to choose a batch number, it brings up all the other values in that row, which include the OS values as well. I need those columns to not appear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, Do Like this, I hope this would helps :

```
SELECT  * FROM( 
    SELECT NSField1 as DataColumnNameSame1,NSField2 as DataColumnNameSame2 FROM SAMETABLE AS NS WHERE NS.BATCH='111111' AND RUNDATE BETWEEN '1/14/13' AND '1/16/13' 

UNION ALL

    SELECT OSField1 as DataColumnNameSame1,OSField2 as DataColumnNameSame2 FROM SAMETABLE AS NS WHERE OS.BATCH='111111' AND RUNDATE BETWEEN '1/14/13' AND '1/16/13' 

) AS DATA 
    --WHERE CRITERIA IF NECESSARY IN THIS LEVEL TOO, ONCE AGAIN YOU CAN FILTER FROM HERE ALSO IF NEEDED. HOPE THIS HELPS.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this way :

```
where (NSHeatBatch= 'G22166' or OSHeatBatch= 'G22166') 
and RunDate between '1/14/13' and '1/16/13'
```

Many times your Braces are so much important things to define query. Lets try that way...!

Comment: This helps but it also allows all values in that row to appear. Lets say a user doesn't know if the batch is on the New side or Old, they just know that it was made between two dates. How would they be able to make a graph if both NS and OS values appear?

Comment: Then, You have to put an OR operator between that two conditions. So, whether the Batch Matched or in between dates,both will appear. Otherwise, Im feeling now that you to have split your table into 2 for NEW SIDE and OLD Side. Then you can query from the Both tables using and retrieve the data with UNION with the Conditions on both tables.

Comment: I don't have permission to make a new table. Would an if else or case statement work?